# Call parent static method in php

Tags: php, inheritance, static

I have a base class A:

```
class A {
   public static function a() {
      ...
   }
   public static function b() {
      ...
   }
}
```

and an extended class B

```
class B extends A {
   public static function a() {
      ...
   }
   public static function c() {
      ...
   }
}
```

I would like to be able to call all the methods using B::
How would I call A::b, using B::?

Answer (score 32):

You should be able to accomplish this as easily as:

```
class B extends A {
   public static function a() {
      parent::a();
   }
}
```

[See the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php#example-203)

Comment: @brent The link to the docs returns a 404 Not Found. Can you please update the answer?

Comment: @user773093 Works for me. Please re-check? :)