# php - calling static function from a extended class

Tags: php, static

I cant manage to call a static function (with a constant) from a extended class. Here is my code:

```
(1st file)
class A
{                        
    function isXSet()
    {
        return X;
    }        
    public static function setX()
    {
        define('X', 1);
    }
}  

(second file)

include('/*first file*/');
class B extends A
{        
    A::setX();        
}
```

How can i manage to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call parent static method in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636171/call-parent-static-method-in-php)

Comment: It should work if you call it from somewhere. If you take a look, that `A::setX();` is just 'flying around' (it's not inside a method)...

Comment: @FirstOne - why is this 'flying aroun' ? How can I call that then ?

Comment: I mean, look at the code. In that place, you define class properties and methods. You don't call stuff in there..

Comment: Your class `B` has __no__ methods.

Comment: And a side note, if you call `setX()` on `B`, it will call A's method because you extended it (without overriding)

Comment: That could be considered basic OOP / PHP (please, learn oop concepts and then how to apply them in php)

Answer (score 1):

Your code here

```
class B extends A
{        
    A::setX();        
}
```

is a little off. You didn't put your call inside of a method.

```
class B extends A
{   
    public static function doSomething() {     
        A::setX();
    }
}
```

This isn't actually doing anything by means of the parent/child relationship. In fact, after you define `class A`, the call to `A::setX()` can happen anywhere since it's public and static. This code is just as valid:

```
class A
{
    function isXSet()
    {
        return X;
    }
    public static function setX()
    {
        define('X', 1);
    }
}

class B { // No extending!
    function isXSet() {
        return A::isXSet();
    }
}
```

What you're more likely looking for is `parent` instead:

```
class A
{
    public function isXSet()
    {
        return X;
    }

    protected static function setX()
    {
        define('X', 1);
    }
}

class B extends A
{   
    public static function doSomething() {     
        parent::setX();
        var_dump( parent::isXSet() ); // int(1)
    }
}
```

A big plus here is that extending classes can access *protected* methods and properties from the `parent` class. This means you could keep everyone else from being able to call `A::setX()` unless the callee was an instance of or child of `A`.

Comment: I think I shoul let You know what I want to do - I want to set constant from a class B, and than check in class A if constant X is set (then do sth) - how can I do that ?