# Yii2 - loadMultiple with form model

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a very simple scenario where I'm receiving a list of `Variance Positions` from the end user. To be able to validate the structure of the input, I created the following model for the single item that I should receive:

```
class VariancePositionsForm extends Model{
    public $id;
    public $position;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id','position'], 'required'],
            [['id', 'position'], 'integer'],
        ];
    }
}
```

And in the controller, I have the following:

```
    $variancePositions = [];
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof(Yii::$app->request->post());$i++)
    {
        $variancePositions[]  = new VariancePositionsForm(); 
    }
    VariancePositionsForm::loadMultiple($variancePositions, Yii::$app->request->post());
```

When I try to `var_dump($variancePositions)` however, I'm finding that its empty. In other words, `loadMultiple()` is not loading the models. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: content of `Yii::$app->request->post()`?

Comment: Just updated the question with the content :)

Comment: What `loadMultiple()` returns? true or false.  You should call `Model::loadMultiple()` not `VariancePositionsForm::loadMultiple()` i guess. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636171/call-parent-static-method-in-php)

Comment: This is not it unfortunately

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean I tried Model::loadMultiple() and it did not work :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163323/discussion-between-insane-skull-and-mrateb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't load the model from the form, only from json you have to add an empty string into the last parameter in this function:

```
VariancePositionsForm::loadMultiple($variancePositions, Yii::$app->request->post(), '');
```

look here:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Model.php#L884

Comment: Thank you very much. This was extremely helpful :)